# encoding issue with python requests library

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, python-requests, iso-8859-1

i was trying earlier today to parse a web page fetched by python3 requests library with beautifulsoup, here is the link:
https://azuremlsdktestpypi.azureedge.net/codegen

```
response = requests.get('https://azuremlsdktestpypi.azureedge.net/codegen')
```

i tried to get all the links, with:

```
ph = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
ph.findAll('a')
```

but couldn't get any results, and what confuses me more is when i tried to search for a string in response.text, the string does exist  in response.text but the interpreter couldn't find it.
I think the problem is with encodings because type(response.text) returned "<type 'unicode'>", but response.encoding returned 'ISO-8859-1'.
so I would be grateful if anyone can help me try to figure out how to deal with such responses.

Regards

Comment: `.text` is already decoded; use `.content` if you need the original bytes. See also [the paragraph on encodings from the doc](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#encodings).

Comment: thank you, i am still confused i tried to search for "azureml-contrib-reinforcementlearning" in response.text and the result was false, so then tried to search for it in response.content and the same thing happened.

Comment: how did you make that search?

Comment: "azureml-contrib-reinforcementlearning" in response.text

Comment: oh yes there's that bom